# iPhone, what background colors should I use for a personal finance app?

Tags: iphone

I know this question might be considered better on Stack UI, but I wanted some opinions from fellow app developers.

I've designed my app with black opaque navigation bars, and dark colored backgrounds. I've produced some radial gradient backgrounds in my paint program. I have three different images (plus a second set for retina). One has a dark green to black gradient, another dark yellow to black and a dark blue to black gradient.

So my app looks quite dark.

I didn't think this was a problem.

However me colleague thinks this is a very bad idea, that it will make people think their money will disappear into a black hole.

I'd like to use different colors backgrounds as I have one view I use in edit and add mode, to differentiate them. Also it makes each screen more distinctive.

I've also had a look round to see if you can buy sets of backgrounds, but I've only seen wallpaper sites for users to use.

I want to make my app seem cool, thats why I've gone for a dark scheme. But I'm now a little worried that it will affect sales.

I'd like some opinions please. I don't really want to post any of my screens as I haven't released my app / idea yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree that a dark scheme probably isn't the best but have you looked at other apps? Mint uses a nice contrast of dark headers with white (or light) content areas. They even have a nice textured background if you drill to the transaction view.  I'm using a very light green in an app I'm working on that could go really well with dark nav bars and a dark green-ish/black font.  It could at least be a nice background color bumping up against dark borders.

[UIColor colorWithRed:196/255.0 green:218/255.0 blue:173/255.0 alpha:1.0]

However, I will say that it's difficult to recommend a color scheme without seeing what kind of ui you're dealing with (how many elements and of what type, etc).

good luck...

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.noupe.com/showcases/showcase-well-designed-banking-and-investment-websites.html

IMO, Go with light Grey

```
#eee
```

Also see http://www.mybanktracker.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think using the banks colours is best for brand recognition, the [National Bank iBank](http://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/national-bank-ibank/id289189280?mt=8) app does this well.